# Estou tentando criar um Trigger em MySql mas está dando erro de sintaxe

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER comissao
ON tb_Pedido
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
v_codFuncionario INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE v_dataPedido DATETIME(3) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE v_valorComissao DECIMAL(15,4) DEFAULT NULL

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) = 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED) = 1 
THEN
SET v_codFuncionario = (SELECT codFuncionario FROM DELETED);
SET v_dataPedido = (SELECT dataPedido FROM DELETED);
DELETE FROM tb_Comissao WHERE dataPedido = v_dataPedido AND codFuncionario = v_codFuncionario;

SET v_codFuncionario = (SELECT codFuncionario FROM INSERTED);
SET v_dataPedido = (SELECT dataPedido FROM INSERTED);
SET v_valorComissao = (SELECT totalPedido FROM INSERTED); * 0.05
INSERT INTO tb_Comissao (codFuncionario, dataPedido, valorComissao) VALUES (v_codFuncionario, v_dataPedido, v_valorComissao);
ELSE
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) = 1
THEN
SET v_codFuncionario = (SELECT codFuncionario FROM INSERTED);
SET v_dataPedido = (SELECT dataPedido FROM INSERTED);
SET v_valorComissao = (SELECT totalPedido FROM INSERTED); * 0.05
INSERT INTO tb_Comissao (codFuncionario, dataPedido, valorComissao) VALUES (v_codFuncionario, v_dataPedido, v_valorComissao);
ELSE
SET v_dataPedido = (SELECT dataPedido FROM DELETED);
DELETE FROM tb_comissao WHERE dataPedido = v_dataPedido AND codFuncionario = v_codFuncionario;
END IF;
END IF;
END
```

> ## 1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'ON tb_Pedido

Comment: Poste o erro !!

Comment: #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'ON tb_Pedido

Comment: Arthur, quando precisar adicionar algo, clique em "editar" abaixo de sua pergunta, e inclua. Assim fica completa e de melhor entendimento aos demais :]

Comment: Tente colocar `CREATE TRIGGER comissao
ON nome_do_seu_banco.tb_Pedido`

Comment: não seria o evento antes, assim: `CREATE TRIGGER comissao
BEFORE INSERT ON tb_Pedido...`? Veja a documentação https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html  e exemplos  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: ok irei ver, desde já mt obrigado

Comment: @RicardoPontual acho que não. O que pode ser é que tenha que definir um evento só entre `FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`... Por exemplo `BEFORE UPDATE`, `AFTER INSERT`, etc

Comment: @RBZ fiz um teste no sqlfiddle e não funciona, mas seguindo a sintaxe da documentação funciona (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c89b3)  essa sintaxe acima seu que funciona no `sql-server` mas no `mySql` parece que não

Comment: Acredito que teria de substituir o for insert por BEFORE ou AFTER .

Comment: @RicardoPontual exatamente!... eu estava olhando no `sql-server`, e me confundi nesse link: [MySQL Básico: Triggers](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-basico-triggers/37462) , não vi a palavra "evento" aqui `CREATE TRIGGER nome momento evento`. Desculpa aí pessoal.

Comment: Exato, eu também fui olhar a documentação porque *trigger* não é algo que você cria a toda hora, e nem sabia que a sintaxe era um pouco diferente, estamos sempre aprendendo :)

Comment: Obrigado a todos, segui a documentação do Mysql e consegui criar a trigger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como citado nos comentários pelo Ricardo, sua estrutura está incorreta no cenário `MySql`.

Exemplo da estrutura:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_ItensVenda_Insert AFTER INSERT
ON ItensVenda
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Produtos SET Estoque = Estoque - NEW.Quantidade
WHERE Referencia = NEW.Produto;
END$

CREATE TRIGGER Tgr_ItensVenda_Delete AFTER DELETE
ON ItensVenda
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Produtos SET Estoque = Estoque + OLD.Quantidade
WHERE Referencia = OLD.Produto;
END$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

Exemplo no seu código:

```
CREATE TRIGGER comissao AFTER INSERT
ON tb_Pedido
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
```

---

Assim, precisa definir o momento do "disparo" da trigger:

**BEFORE**: antes

**AFTER**: depois

**Opções**: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

---

Link: [MySQL Básico: Triggers](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-basico-triggers/37462)